# Active tab is not switching when clicked on?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have posted the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/6sduqv7k/ The JS I have removed since it wasn't working to change the tabs but I have posted it in here. Any help is appreciated.

```
$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    $("#tabs").tabs("select", this.hash);
});


# OR

$("#tabs").tabs();
$(".nexttab").click(function() {
    var selected = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected");
    $("#tabs").tabs("option", "selected", selected + 1);
});
```

Comment: You are not loading any javascript files, it can't work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/b1u5z9gL/ I edited my fiddle

Comment: What is this snippet of javascript? I simply copied and pasted it from some random page?